# SwiftUI WebView: This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness

Tags: swift, swiftui, wkwebview, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to have a list of NavigationLinks that show a website in full screen. But when I tap on the NavigationLink I get the warning: "This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness."

Here is a small example to reproduce the error:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Apple") {
                    WebViewScreen(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WebViewScreen: View {
    let url: URL
    @State private var isWebViewLoading = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            WebViewRepresentable(
                isLoading: $isWebViewLoading,
                url: url
            )
            if isWebViewLoading {
                ProgressView()
                    .scaleEffect(1.5)
                    .tint(.accentColor)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WebViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var isLoading: Bool
    let url: URL
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {}

    func makeCoordinator() -> WebViewCoordinator {
        WebViewCoordinator(isLoading: $isLoading)
    }
}

class WebViewCoordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @Binding var isLoading: Bool

    init(isLoading: Binding<Bool>) {
        _isLoading = isLoading
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        isLoading = true
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        isLoading = false
    }
}
```

The warning does not appear without if I only show the WebViewScreen.

Comment: Apple broke it. See this [response by Quinn the Eskimo](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714467?answerId=734799022#734799022) And feel free to file a feedback to add pressure for them to fix it.