# This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am using `ShareLink` from the latest `SwiftUI` and when I click it I get this warning on `@main`.
`ShareLink` was introduced in `iOS 16` so I was wondering if anyone else came across this warning.
I can see other questions related to similar warning but they are about `WebKit`. Maybe `ShareLink` is using it under the hood but I don't see it in documentation.
The related questionsI found are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74038451/in-xcode-14-ios-16-purple-warnings-starting-with-this-method-should-not-be-ca), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75039938/swiftui-webview-this-method-should-not-be-called-on-the-main-thread-as-it-may-l) or [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/xcode-14-warning-this-method-should-not-be-called-on-the-main-thread-as-it-may-lead-to-ui-unresponsiveness/17431).
I tried to put it inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` but is not working.
This is minimal code to reproduce the warning.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ShareLink(item: URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com")!)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Running on `XCode 14.2` for `iOS 16.2`.

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, can't reproduce. I see no warning with your code, either compiling or running.

Comment: Upgrade XCode to 14.3 and the warning is gone.

Comment: That would be why! :)

Comment: I see this still in XCode 15.0 (15A240d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bug by Apple and Apple was also aware of this bug. It has already been fixed in XCode 14.3.